# Rails недоступен метод current_user в WebsocketRails::BaseController (в production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, devise

Не могу получить метод `current_user` в контроллерах наследуемых от WebsocketRails :: BaseController (в среде production). Нет никакой ошибки в журнале, контроллер просто прекращает выполнение. Я вывожу в лог current_user и в среде development я вижу значение, а в среде production переменная пуста. Подскажите в чем существенная разница запуска `rails s -e development` и `rails s -e production`?

Я даже пытался скопировать конфиги из дева в продакшн (config/environments/production.rb). Но все по прежнему.

Использую следующие gem'ы для Руби 2.2.0 и рельсы 4.2.0 рельсы:

```
websocket-rails (0.7.0)
faye-websocket (0.9.2)
websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
devise (3.4.1)
```

Соответственно сервер Thin, для вебсокетоа запускаю rake websocket_rails `websocket_rails:start_server` на 3001 порту и подключаюсь к нему корректно.

Если обращаться не к `current_user`, а просто вытащить с базы любого user'a, то метод отрабатывает без проблем, то есть сокеты в порядке, соединение есть, единственное Devise'овский current_user контроллер не видит, и это только в среде production.

После успешной авторизации в development'е в логе:

```
current_user:#<User:0x00000005bfe988>
```

В production'e в логе:

```
current_user:
```

Пусто, хотя поменялась лишь среда.

P.S. с базой всё в порядке, не websockets'ные методы работаю корректно.

Comment: Вы запускаете сервер Websocket-rails в режиме Standalone. Правильно я понял?

Comment: Да, правильно понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить метод в контроллер, который наследуется от `WebsocketRails :: BaseController`

```
def cookies
    request.cookies
end
```

И ещё: по умолчанию, когда вы пишите команду `rake websocket_rails:start_server`, то Rails запускается в режиме `development`, а следовательно использует конфигурацию для базы данных из режима `development`, затем, при соединении происходит ошибка соединения, которая пишется в `log/development` (где её и не догадаешься искать).

Чтобы запустить Standalone Websocket сервер в режиме `production` используйте команду

```
rake websocket_rails:start_server RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Благодарю! `rake websocket_rails:start_server RAILS_ENV=production` - помогло.